# Progress Bar on top when clicking a new link

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a progress bar when someone clicks a link on the page. The effect i would like to have is similar as youtube.com

That is, when this script is activated a progress bar on top is shown (note: NOT on page load of the new link), and when the new page is loaded the content is updated by replacing all the content of the **`<body>`**

Is there any script like this? Without having to change every link on the page

The closest match I have got is this example:

```
$(".ajax-call").loadingbar({
  target: "#loadingbar-frame",
  replaceURL: false,
  direction: "right",

  /* Default Ajax Parameters.  */
  async: true, 
  complete: function(xhr, text) {},
  cache: true,
  error: function(xhr, text, e) {},
  global: true,
  headers: {},
  statusCode: {},
  success: function(data, text, xhr) {},
  dataType: "html",
  done: function(data) {}
});
```

Explained here: https://onextrapixel.com/loadingbar-js-adding-a-youtube-like-loading-bar-to-your-website/

But is there something better?

Comment: It sounds like you want the behaviours of a SPA (single page application). They don't really browse to another page, hence their ability to seemingly load another page 'in the background'. Your browser won't do this with a typical multi page application.

Comment: @JamieWeston: this would be a progressive web application style, i..e: by default the link is a standard link that without javascript just redirects you to the target link. With this script enabled, it would load the page with ajax and replace it the content of the body and in the meanwhile it shows the loading bar on top. It's not a SPA by default. It is what the plugin I have posted does

Comment: Loading bars like that only work while you're still on the same page. You can't stay on page A, load all assets for page B, then tell your browser to go to page B. If you want that behaviour, you should already be building a SPA.

Comment: @JamieWeston: maybe you misunderstood: the procedure is the following when the script is activated, on click of a new link the new body content is loaded with AJAX and replaced in the current page. The history at this point is manged with the History API. It's not what you described. See this to understand: https://onextrapixel.com/loadingbar-js-adding-a-youtube-like-loading-bar-to-your-website/

Comment: I looked at the link when I read your answer. Sharing your link again doesn't change the question. Everything you have described sounds best suited to a SPA. It seems strange to go to this much effort to 'fake' a SPA experience. Updating the body of a page with new content is exactly what a real SPA will do.

Comment: I don't want SPA pages, they have some serious issues https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-i-hate-your-single-page-app-f08bb4ff9134 I prefer the concept of progressive javascript enhancement